# How can I put IDs into an array, retrieve the image url and then display in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, echo

Currently have the following at the top of my php file

```
$post1->ID = 85;
$post2->ID = 87;
$post3->ID = 89;
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post1->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
$image2 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post2->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
$image3 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post3->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
```

And then further down in my file where I want to output the URL of the image

```
style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')"
style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image2[0]; ?>')"
style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image3[0]; ?>')"
```

A lot of repeated code however I am unsure on how to put the post ids in an array.

Would I be correct in setting the array up like

```
$post->ID = array(85, 87, 89);
```

But I am unsure on the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

```
$post_array = array(85, 87, 95);
foreach($post_array as $p)
{
   $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $p ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );

/* enter code here to output HMTL element use $img to set BG img */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply would it be possible to put the id in an array (well we know this can be done) and then when i go echo the url do $img[2] to get the third url in the array

Answer (score 0):

I have looked your code and this is how I would do it:

```
<?php
//An array to store your ID's
$post->ID = array(85, 87, 89);

//For loop to start counting from zero
//For i = 0; When i is smaller or exactly the number of elements in the ID-array; Increment i by one
for($i=0; $i<=count($post->id); $i++){
//Creating the image-array
$image[] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID[$i] ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
}

//And then looping the final $image -array:
//For i = 0; When i is smaller or exactly the number of elements in the image-array; Increment i by one
for($i=0; $i<count($image); $i++){
//Where we echo out the final result through a for-loop:
echo 'style="background-image: url('{$image[$i]}')"';

}
```

By using loops and arrays you make your code drastically more dynamic.